# Fatal error: Class 'BaseObject' not found in sQcrm

Tags: php

I'm trying to install http://sqcrm.com and when I finish with the Setup steps I receive this error.

```
Fatal error: Class 'BaseObject' not found in /home/public_html/class/core/radria/DataObject.class.php on line 9
```

And this is the code the php file have:

```
<?php
class DataObject extends BaseObject {
//-- values array to hold key value data
protected $values = Array();
//-- holds the key for values array
public $fields;
//-- holds the db conn object from Doctrine
public $dbcon ;
//-- holds the table name
public $table ;
//-- holds the primary_key of a table
protected $primary_key = '';
//-- holds the result set of a query
public $result ;
//-- holds the string sql query
public $sql_query = '';
```

`
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If `BaseObject` is not defined in the same file (and it looks like it is not) and if you are not using an autoload mechanism (which I also daresay you are not) you need to éxplictly include the file that contains `BaseObject`.

Comment: @Almostwo a new version of sqcrm is up and auto include is implemented to sort out these issues, also in next few days a lot of new changes/ code improvement will be deployed.

Comment: Thanks Abhik, Its possible to have your email ?